# Java - How can one replace a variable in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array, replace

**Question:**

How can one replace a variable in a 2D array

**Reiteration:**

In this specific case, we have a 2D array (named board) with each element assigned to a letter in the alphabet from a - i.

```
    int[][] board = new int [3 /*row*/][3 /*column*/];
    int a = board[0][0];
    int b = board[0][1];
    int c = board[0][2];
    int d = board[1][0];
    int e = board[1][1];
    int f = board[1][2];
    int g = board[2][0];
    int h = board[2][1];
    int i = board[2][2];
```

Then, we check if there is repeats within the array using "if-statements".

`if (a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e || a == f || a == g || a == h || a == i)`

`if (b == c || b == d || b == e || b == f || b == g || b == h || b == i)`

`if (c == d || c == e || c == f || c == g || c == h || c == i)`

`if (d == e || d == f || d == g || d == h || d == i)`

`if (e == f || e == g || e == h || e == i)`

`if (f == g || f == h || f == i)`

`if (g == h || g == i)`

`if (h == i)`

I know this is a very slow and inefficient way to solve this with if-statements. I will ask another question in StackOverflow regarding reducing these if-statements into a for-loop.

Now, after we finish these statements, lets use this particular line of code:

```
    if (a == b || a == c || a == d || a == e || a == f || a == g || a == h || a == i)
```

And just for this example, let us say the value of "a" equals the value of "b".

And now, we want to replace all values of "b" in the 2D array with "a".

This means that our end result should have no longer have any of the variable "b" in it.

**Attempt:**

If you could understand, I usually put my attempts on my posts. However, in this case, I don't understand the concept and cannot try to solve it on my own. I could only remember that there might be a function called "replace" in JAVA in which we can use to solve the problem. My attempt can be considered as writing out the if-statements. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you replacing `b` with `a`, since they are already the same?

Comment: to help me solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding your question correctly, I would probably do something like this:

```java
int[][] board = new int [3 /*row*/][3 /*column*/];
int a = board[0][0];
int b = board[0][1];

// ...

for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == b) {
         board[i][j] = a;
      }
   }
}
```

Basically, this loops over all of the values of the 2D array, and when it finds a value that equals the value of `b`, it replaces that value with the value of `a`.